# CouchDB filtered replication for docs AND fields

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

It is clear how to do filtered replication to get only certain docs.

However, I want to take it a step further to get only certain fields from those docs.

The goal is to ensure unwanted fields never exist in the target db; the target db's docs should only have the fields I specify.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Filter functions only determine if the document will be replicated or no. What you would need is an update_handler associated the replication but that's not possible.

Comment: You mention "unwanted" fields. Can you give some more background on why you want to get rid of some fields? That would give us the opportunity to look broader to the options available.

Comment: @AlexisCôté thanks for the input - I suppose then the workaround you elude to involves not using replication at all; perhaps follow the change feed and invoke some logic to update target db with these customized docs that way.

Comment: @kroonwijk Let's say you have a database of users; one doc per user. When a user makes changes to their profile, their doc is updated (via a call to your custom API such that the client never talks to this db directly; this db is server-side only).  It might be nice though if there was a public db that has a copy of each doc, say for the purpose of public profile pages, with said doc containing none of the private info like password, etc.  Hence the idea proposed here, ie- invoke a server-side live replication that will send a trimmed/censored version of each doc to the public db.

Comment: @Derrick I had a similar design with one of my application. I had a public profile document wich contained all the public information of the user. I also had another private document that contained all the private fields. Whenever the user updated his profile, I was updating both the documents if necessary.

Comment: @AlexisCôté yeah decent setup, another approach is to listen to changes feed of your users db and then post a filtered version of the doc to the target public db on every change - I'm leaning to this since it feels a bit more automated; less intertwined with the application logic (and more along the lines of the original idea/hope of having it happen apart of replication)